# How do I install Python?

Tags: python

I am new to ubuntu and will be focusing on machine learning. Can anyone please provide a step by step guidance for python installation on my system?

Answer (score 7):

Python is installed by default in Ubuntu. Open a terminal by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>T</kbd> shortcut and type `python` to enter it's interactive shell. You don't need to install anything.

The python shell will look something like this: (the version number won't match since I'm on 12.04)

```
Python 2.7.3 (default, Aug  1 2012, 05:16:07) 
[GCC 4.6.3] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

Comment: I suggest using `ipython` instead of `python` as an interactive shell.

Comment: ipython is not installed by default
I have found a package for machine learning. It might be useful for you.
python-scikits-learn - Python modules for machine learning and data mining

Answer (score 1):

Answers above are complete for your question. But for machine learning you probably can provide us with more information what exactly you want to do. Probably you will need some additional libraries, for sure numpy, matplotlib, scipy which are the base on this type of problems, but also you need to decide what data format you have. For example I use pandas to have R-like dataFrame where I have different type of data with named rows and columns. 
My point is. that at some point you need to know which Python version you have and which you want (pandas require at least some versions of libraries) what type of machine learning you going to use and what type of data you going to proceed.
From that point your question can get better/precise answers.

Answer (score 0):

Python is installed by default in Ubuntu. Further if you want to update, try the following command when connected to the Internet.

Open a terminal and type the following command

```
sudo apt-get install python
```